# Why IntelliSense doesn't show the item's properties with DataGrid built-in columns?

Tags: wpf, xaml, intellisense, wpfdatagrid, design-time

I have this ViewModel classes:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}

public class Container
{
    public string ContainerName { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; }
}
```

I use them in the XAML of my Window to help the IntelliSense at DesignTime:

```
<Window x:Class="DesignTime.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesignTime"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:Container, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"/>
```

Now the IntelliSense recognizes the properties of the `Container`:

[image]

So I create an `ItemsControl` bound to the `Items` list of the `Container`. When I write the bindings of the `DataTemplate` of the single displayed item, the IntelliSense now shows me the properties of the `Item` class:

[image]

The same happens if I use a `ListBox` or a `ListView`.

But with a `DataGrid` something goes wrong. If I create a column with a built-in template, like `DataGridTextColumn`, the IntelliSense shows me the `Container`'s properties, not the `Item`'s one!

[image]

Same for the other built-in columns: `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, etc.

However, if I write a custom template using the `DataGridTemplateColumn`, it works well like the `ItemsControl`.

Why is this happening? How can I make the IntelliSense to work correctly with the `DataGrid`'s built-in columns (if it's possible)?

Comment: A DataGridColumn is not a FrameworkElement that gets added to the visual tree and it doesn't have a DataContext. The root element of a DataTemplate does get added to the visual tree and has a DataContext though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Probably because a `DataGridColumn` is not a `FrameworkElement` that gets added to the visual tree. It doesn't have a `DataContext`. The root element of a `DataTemplate` does get added to the visual tree and has a `DataContext` though. That's the difference.

> Your answer seems reasonable, but there's a thing that I still found weird. I would expect an implicit `DataTemplate` also for built-in columns like `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. How could it be rendered as a `CheckBox` otherwise?

The `CheckBox` is built eventually at runtime, not at design time. The designer doesn't run all code that is executed at runtime.

Comment: Your answer seems reasonable, but there's a thing that I still found weird. I would expect an implicit `DataTemplate` also for built-in columns like `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`. How could it be rendered as a CheckBox otherwise?

Comment: Obviously I consider this behavior a lack of feature in Visual Studio.